# ASP.NET LINQ (C#) UPDATE SYNTAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq-to-entities

I am using LINQ to Entities in an ASP.NET C# app. The below code is my attempt to update (or reset, really) a value 'AvgRideTime' in my sql db to null. However it seems to do nothing, no errors, just nothing. Any thoughts?

```
protected void ResetAvgRT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (RamRideOpsEntities myEntities = new RamRideOpsEntities())
            {
                var avgTime = (from a in myEntities.AdminOptions
                               select a.AvgRideTime).First();

                if (avgTime != null)
                {
                    avgTime = null;
                    myEntities.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var avgTime = myEntities.AdminOptions.First();

            if (avgTime != null)
            {
                avgTime.AvgRideTime = null;
                myEntities.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Try the above code.

Comment: Cool, looks like we have a winner ( :
..I'm using a gridview though for the display, what would be the best way to update that display? Is there a way other than manually setting the value shown?

Answer (score 1):

avgTime this is link to object and when you set avgTime = null, avgTime no referenced to object, but myEntities.AdminOptions contains this object.

Comment: ah, makes sense..if its just a reference then all I was doing is setting the ref to null. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the avgTime gets a null value.

Comment: good thought, but I checked, it is indeed getting the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
protected void ResetAvgRT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (RamRideOpsEntities myEntities = new RamRideOpsEntities())
    {
        var avgTime = (from a in myEntities.AdminOptions
                           select a).First();
        if (a.avgTime != null)
        {
            a.avgTime = null;
            myEntities.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified;
            myEntities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```